# Subsetting rows from a dataframe using column names from a second matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to subset a dataframe of country population sizes using the column names of a matrix giving disease numbers by nation. My intent is to calculate per capita disease rates to compare between nations.

Here's a bit of sample data similar to my own:

```
country = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra")

population_by_country <- data.frame(country = country, population = c(39074280, 2877239, 43984569, 55169, 77287))

disease = matrix(rep(1:5, 5), ncol = 5, nrow = 5)
colnames(disease) <- country
```

My challenge is to ensure that the row of countries in the dataframe match those in the matrix columns. Once I get that, extracting a vector of population sizes, then dividing the matrix by the vector to get disease per capita will be simple.

What I tried:

```
names <- colnames(disease)
population <- match(names, population_by_country_2020)
```

Unfortunately, that just gave me a vector of NA's. Next I tried

```
library(dplyr)
population_2020 <- as.data.frame(t(population_by_country_2020)) %>% select(all_of(names))
```

which resulted in a lengthy error message about unknown columns and then listing all the "unknown" columns.

I know I'm missing something, probably something simple that will make me slap my forehead and yell "DOH!", but at this moment, I'm stumped. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want something like `population_by_country %>% dplyr::filter(country %in% colnames(disease))` ? Also, I think life will be easier if `disease` is converted to a data frame with countries in one column, and then joined with `population_by_country `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to tell the match function which table it should match against.

```
country = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra")

population_by_country <- data.frame(country = country, population = c(39074280, 2877239, 43984569, 55169, 77287))

disease = matrix(rep(1:5, 5), ncol = 5, nrow = 5)
colnames(disease) <- country

all.equal.character(colnames(population_by_country), colnames(disease))


to_select <- colnames(disease) %in% population_by_country$country

# alternative using match
to_select_match <- match(colnames(disease), population_by_country$country)

print(to_select)
print(to_select_match)
```